# Doctrine | CASE WHEN в SELECT

Tags: php, doctrine2

Добрый день.
Составляю в Doctrine запрос.

```
...
->addSelect('(CASE WHEN c.type = 1 THEN ( SUM(c.amountMain) AND COUNT(c.id) ) ELSE 0 END)')
```

Хочу чтобы при исполнении условия возвращало **SUM(c.amountMain)** и **COUNT(c.id)**

Помогите пожалуйста оформить запрос.

Comment: Если это SQL то вы чего то странного хотите. Что означает "происходило" SUM и COUNT, что оно должно вам вернуть то ?

Comment: @Mike нужно чтобы вернуло сумму и колличество суммированых элементов. Если не добавляю COUNT, то все отлично работает. Но мне нужно и то и другое.

Comment: Одно выражение - одна колонка. нужно два результата - делайте 2 выражения, т.е. в SQL это выглядело бы `(case ... sum()), (case ... count())`. И вообще немного странное условие. У вас в запросе group by по колонке c.type ? Просто так как у вас написано c.type в case должен быть проверен для каждой строки, т.е. до группировки, а sum() и count() будут учитывать много строк, т.е. после группировки

Comment: @Mike так и думал, что не получится упростить задачу. Нет, я не использовал group by, нужно было чтобы условие проверилось для каждой строки. Спасибо за помощь. Думаю мой вопрос оказался бесполезным для общества и его нужно удалить вообще.

Comment: Что бы для каждой строки - перенесите проверку условия внутрь функции `sum(case ... then amountMain else 0 end)`

Comment: @Mike большое спасибо за помощь. Все работает как нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, действия нужно проводить отдельно. Причем не нужно использовать COUNT() в данном случае, так как будет произведен подсчет всех результатов. Вместо него нужно использовать SUM()

```
->addSelect('SUM((CASE WHEN c.type = 1 THEN c.amountMain ELSE 0 END) as sum')
->addSelect('SUM((CASE WHEN c.type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count')
```